# Downloading iNaturalist images using python

Tags: python, image, web-crawler

I am trying to download images form iNaturalist site:
https://www.inaturalist.org/home

For this I am using the following site:
https://www.inaturalist.org/observations/export

But I would like to download it directly using python script:

```
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen
import urllib.parse

url = 'https://www.inaturalist.org/observations.json?has%5B%5D=photos&quality_grade=research&identifications=most_agree&captive=false&taxon_id=85553'
response = urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(response.read())
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Unfortunately its not working as it bring much less images than the expected number. I think I must be doing something wrong. The url used is the one created through the second site I gave adding at the beginning :'https://www.inaturalist.org/observations.json?'. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: It appears you need to be a member to access that website...

Comment: I am log-in indeed... but its not working, I don't know if I should try another code?

Answer (score 0):

It is limited to 100 observations. You can split your query into multiple queries. However, iNaturalist requests that you not export large numbers of queries.